# hardhat node problem

Tags: hardhat

this is the [hook](https://github.com/saremeskandary/typescript-next.js-hardhat-web3react-tailwind/blob/main/hooks/useGetText.tsx) that I use:

```
export default function useGetText() {
  const { active } = useWeb3React<Web3Provider>();
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>();
  const [id, setId] = useState<BigNumberish>();
  const [click, setClick] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const contract = useTextTokenContract(textContractAddress);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active && click) {
      let a = async () => {
        setText(await contract.getText(id));
      };
      a()
    }
    return setClick(false);
  }, [click]);
  return {text, setClick, setId};
}
```

when I use that I will get this error:

```
Error: call revert exception (method="getText(uint256)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

in hardhat node's terminal of [my template projct](https://github.com/saremeskandary/typescript-next.js-hardhat-web3react-tailwind)
I will get this:

```bash
eth_feeHistory

  Errors encountered in param 1: Invalid value "0x-e20" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/0: QUANTITY, Invalid value "0x-e20" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/1: { blockNumber: QUANTITY }, Invalid value "0x-e20" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/2: { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined }, Invalid value "0x-e20" supplied to : (QUANTITY | { blockNumber: QUANTITY } | { blockHash: DATA, requireCanonical: boolean | undefined } | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending")/3: "earliest" | "latest" | "pending"
```

in ropsetn it work's well.
I used **web3-react** and **metamask** for provider.
I work with **windows10 wsl2** and my IDE is **vscode**

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: yes. I don't remember exactly what it was. but I think it was hardhat node problem and I needed to use `npx hardhat clean` and redeploy it

Comment: Hmm tried that and still not working.. this is my error Errors encountered in param 0: Invalid value "0x02" supplied to : RpcFilterRequest/fromBlock: (QUANTITY | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending") | undefined/0: QUANTITY, Invalid value "0x02" supplied to : RpcFilterRequest/fromBlock: (QUANTITY | "earliest" | "latest" | "pending") | undefined/1: "earliest" | "latest" | "pending"

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old hex values instead of abi encoded uint256 values solved this for me. ie `0x2` instead of `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`.